# replacing some of the text in the PHP script with notepad++ at once

Tags: php, notepad++

I need to replace some PHP script with a form like this:

the original text:

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET fill = '$_POST[aaa]' WHERE id = '1'");
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET fill = '$_POST[bbb]' WHERE id = '2'");
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET fill = '$_POST[ccc]' WHERE id = '3'");
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET fill = '$_POST[ddd]' WHERE id = '4'");
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET fill = '$_POST[eee]' WHERE id = '5'");
```

changed to:

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET fill = '$aaa' WHERE id = '1'");
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET fill = '$bbb' WHERE id = '2'");
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET fill = '$ccc' WHERE id = '3'");
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET fill = '$ddd' WHERE id = '4'");
mysql_query ("UPDATE table SET fill = '$eee' WHERE id = '5'");
```

how to replace the entire text at once? I use Notepad ++ as my text editor. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it's regular expression Find-Replace features... A pattern like so

```
\_POST\[(.*)\]
```

(add global match modifier like /g if need)

and replacing it with only

```
$1
```

will work. here https://regex101.com/r/vC8tW7/1 a working demo.